# Ng-serve showing a blank Screen in terminal

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I want to run an Angular project. I have also created 'node_modules' folder and updated the 'Angular CLI'. However, the ng-serve command is not working in terminal.Blank Screen is coming. Node is latest, Npm is latest and Angular -Cli version is coming Mg++ version:Mg++ 1.5beta1 (formerly MicroGnuEmacs Adv.).

EDIT:

[This blank screen is coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXnXa.png)

Please check. I have updated angularCli version also..nothing works

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your terminal?

Comment: I have created 'node_modules' means? you need to run `npm install` and that would automatically install all the required packages. Once everything is properly installed, you need to run `ng serve`, provided your existing project is using the "Angular CLI". Whether or not the project is using Angular CLI can be found out by checking the dev dependencies in `package.json`

Comment: Please tell me step by step how you setup your project. Did you run `ng init` or `ng new` at some point? (Tell me by adding the steps to the original question, click edit)

Comment: Check the console, what is the error there.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

> 1 - sudo apt remove ng-common
>
> 2 - npm cache clear
>
> 3 - alias
>   ng="/home/rafael/npm-global/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng"

Comment: in my case, I fixed with first 2 steps.  
1 - sudo apt remove ng-common
2 - npm cache clear

Comment: The fist two steps should work - I didn't need the alias

Answer (score 0):

It should be 'ng serve' not 'ng-serve'

Comment: Yes I gave ng serve there.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across the same issue. Check your node js version is compatible with angular cli version.

In my case, node js 6.x not supported for angular cli 6.x

So I have updated nodeJs to 8.x

Now its working...

Answer (score 0):

try with this -

sudo apt remove ng-common
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ng
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli